Projector IPV4 Address from server
how can we get IPV4 address & port of a Projector(BenQ) using C# to make a TCP connection. Can we do it? and my application server is different from Projector.
I am trying to achieve it to send command without using remote.

How is the IP address assigned?  Is it fixed or are you using DCHP?  Port number is usually fixed and always the same.  A IPV4 device will always contain a MAC number which contains the manufacturer, part, and serial number.  So you can always ping a range of IP addresses and check MAC for a BenQ Projector
